# Can we replace Memory and Harddisk of laptops - Compaq Presario v2000?

Tags: laptop

I have a compaq presari v2000 laptop that is like 4 years old .It has a nice monitor/keyb/speaker . I would like to upgrade it to something that is good according to current standards . Is it possible ? The processor is 1.67  Mobile centrino which is pretty good .
The problem I face is that I cant install Linux etc on it as it throws millions of errors possibly due to old hard disk . Windows XP which is already installed in this machine is pretty fine though . SO I am looking at the option of upgrading this laptop keeping budget in mind  ... any ideas?

Comment: okay , next time I will ask in superuser.com 
but please tell me if this is a RAM that could be compatible ? 
http://cgi.ebay.in/512-MB-DDR-2-RAM-FOR-LAPTOP-ORIGINAL-HP-BOX-PACK_W0QQitemZ320453361746QQcmdZViewItemQQptZLH_DefaultDomain_203?hash=item4a9c824052

Answer (score 2):

It takes regular 2.5 inch 9.5mm PATA disks and they're still available in decent sizes, it'll also take up to 2GB of memory, you'll need 2 x 1GB PC2700 DDR SDRAM 200 pin 2.5V 333MHz SODIMM (HP P/N:367775-001).

Comment: +1 for hunting the specs. It is unlikely that you'll need the specicic HP part - any RAM of that spec will do and you'll probably find it cheaper from other manufacturers (the laptop's warranty is already long dead so that isn't a concern here). If you plan to use Windows on the machine, be sure to have the rescue disc(s) handy (or install disc if you installed Windows yourself) - hopefully you have these from earlier because if the drive has bad sectors then making a set of rescue discs from it now may fail.

Comment: thanks that indeed was a question that I had in mind , btw do u think I can buy a RAM like the one I have mentioned in my question comment and then attach to the existing RAM ? basically is it possible to install  2 512MGB RAM's ?

Comment: It might be possible to install a larger size of memory.  Usually, it is, but check with the documentation for the system first.  I would look to try to find a service manual from hp.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade them by yourself too. Just, look at your memory/harddisk type, and look at the sections at the bottom of the notebook, there should be couple of screws and cover for each component. Some notebooks have memory under the keyboard, some notebooks have disk at the side of the notebook. I guess you can find them by yourself too..